# TestFlight with 1000 users

Tags: ios, testflight

What kind of provisioning profile is necessary for TestFlight to be used with 1000 users, as mentioned in their [faq](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402851-testflight-faq)?

It seems ad hoc only allows up to 100 devices per year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from their website:

> Team member Limit? You can have a team of 1 or a team of 1000 with
>   TestFlight. If you are distributing Ad Hoc signed IPAs please be aware
>   that, according to Apple, you are only allowed 100 devices attached to
>   a developer's account.

So I suppose that you can have a team of 1000 users, but only up to 100 devices can be used. At least that's what I understood.

Hope it helps

Comment: ah, so the hard limit of 100 devices is still set by apple?

Comment: @ina yes, I think so. They explicitly mentioned that Ad Hoc signed IPAs only support up to 100 devices

Comment: There is no limit with the Enterprise program.

Comment: but with the enterprise program, you are explicitly restricted to distributing apps to "your employees". https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Inviting TestFlight Beta Testers

Internal Testers

Get feedback quickly by sharing your beta builds with up to 25 members of your team who have been assigned the Technical or Admin role in iTunes Connect. Each member can test on up to 10 devices.

External Testers

Once you’re ready, you can invite up to 1,000 users who are not part of your development organization to beta test an app that you intend for public release on the App Store. Apps made available to external testers require a Beta App Review and must comply with the full App Store Review Guidelines before testing can begin. A review is required for new versions of your app that contain significant changes. Up to 10 apps can be tested at a time, internally or externally.

Answer (score 0):

As of 13.11.2015, there was an update by Apple:

> To make your TestFlight experience even better, we’ve made some
>   significant changes. You can now invite up to 2000 external testers
>   and up to 25 internal testers per app. You can also test up to 100
>   apps at the same time for up to 60 days, and submit up to 6 updates
>   per day to your external testers.